# Multiline text with different widths?

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

Is it possible to make a multiline text where the lines are different lengths in React Native?

My situation with an example address (could be any string) where the same length rows:

```
const address = 'Circular Quay, Alfred St, Sydney 2021 NSW Alexandria';
return ( 
    <View style={{width: 80}}>
        <Text>{address}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

Desired result:

[image: multiline text with different widths]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this by applying different widths in the texts styles

```
<Text style={{width='200'}}>Text 1</Text>
<Text style={{width='100'}}>Text 2</Text>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since a don't know where to cut the string into two different since its not a monospaced font.

Comment: The important thing is that I only have one string, not two as in your example. Updated the question!

Comment: you can use address.split(',') and put the first two items in a <Text> and the third item in another <Text>

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem can be textAlign prop in Text Component.

```
<View style={{width: 80}}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign:'center'}}>{address}</Text>
</View>
```